# Data manipulation

Tags: r

my data format looks like this.

```
order_id    Prod1   prod2   Prod3   Prod4   Prod5
   A             1     0     1      1     1
   B             0     0     1      1     0
   C             1     1     0      1     1
```

I want to transform this table in a manner such that All order IDs having Products as "1" should be next to each other under a new var called Product i.e.

```
order_id   Prod
A          Prod1
A          Prod3
A          Prod4
A          Prod5
B          Prod3
B          Prod4
```

and so on. I am trying to program it in R. Any help in this regard would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `melt` the data to 'long' format, `subset` the rows where 'value' is 1, and then `order` based on the 'order_id'.

```
library(reshape2)
d1 <- subset(melt(df1, id.var='order_id'), value!=0, select=1:2)
d1[order(d1$order_id),]
#   order_id variable
#1         A    Prod1
#7         A    Prod3
#10        A    Prod4
#13        A    Prod5
#8         B    Prod3
#11        B    Prod4
#3         C    Prod1
#6         C    prod2
#12        C    Prod4
#15        C    Prod5
```

Answer (score 0):

Two alternative solutions:

**1:** using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydf %<>% gather(var, val, -1) %>% filter(val!=0) %>% select(-3) %>% arrange(order_id)
```

**2:** using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)

```
library(data.table)
mydf <- melt(setDT(mydf), 1)[value!=0][, value := NULL][order(order_id)]
```

which both give:

> ```
> > mydf
>     order_id variable
>  1:        A    Prod1
>  2:        A    Prod3
>  3:        A    Prod4
>  4:        A    Prod5
>  5:        B    Prod3
>  6:        B    Prod4
>  7:        C    Prod1
>  8:        C    prod2
>  9:        C    Prod4
> 10:        C    Prod5
> ```